# How to force a function to treat outputs of different objects identically?

Tags: python, oop

I have this part of the code:

```
llm = OpenAI(temperature = 0)
agent = initialize_agent(
    tools,
    llm,
    agent = 'conversational-react-description',
    verbose = True,
    memory = memory,
    return_intermediate_steps = True
)
response = agent(prompt)
```

When I run it I get the "response" (a dictionary) and in it I see the following values:

```
Thought: Do I need to use a tool? Yes
Action: Python Evaluator
Action Input: sin(3)/cos(5)
Observation: 0.4974931989239781
```

Now, I do a small modification, I try to create a wrapper around LLM and give to `initialize_agent` a wrapped llm object:

```
class wrapper(LLM):

    llm: langchain.llms.openai.OpenAI
    log: str

    @property
    def _llm_type(self) -> str:
        return "custom"

    def _call(self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> str:
        reply = self.llm(prompt)
        f = open(self.log, 'a')
        f.write('\n{\n' + prompt + '\n}{\n' + reply + '\n}\n' + '.'*100)
        f.close()
        return reply

    @property
    def _identifying_params(self) -> Mapping[str, Any]:
        """Get the identifying parameters."""
        return {"llm": self.llm}

wllm = wrapper(llm = llm, log = 'output.log')

agent = initialize_agent(
    tools,
    wllm,
    agent = 'conversational-react-description',
    verbose = True,
    memory = memory,
    return_intermediate_steps = True
)
response = agent(prompt)
```

My expectation was that I should get the same output. However, it is not the case. Now, in the reply dictionary I see the following output:

```
Thought: Do I need to use a tool? Yes
Action: Python Evaluator
Action Input: sin(3)/cos(5)
Observation: 0.8390075430348345
Observation: 0.4974931989239781
```

Note, that there is addition line with "Observation".

I guess that the wrapper itself does not alter the output of the wrapped llm object. I believe that the `agent` object treats the output of `llm` and `wllm` (non-wrapped and wrapped objects) differently.

So, my question is what can be a reason for it? How can I achieve that agent treats llm and wllm (their outputs, to be precise) identically?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer to the question by asking GPT-4. The problem was that the `_call` method in the wrapper class is not forwarding the `stop` and other additional parameters to the wrapped LLM's call method.

So, this part of the code:

```
def _call(self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None) -> str:
    reply = self.llm(prompt)
```

Needed to be replace by this:

```
def _call(self, prompt: str, stop: Optional[List[str]] = None, **kwargs) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    reply = self.llm(prompt, stop=stop, **kwargs)
```